# Exact term for Java prebuilt class and interface library

Tags: java, terminology

I am helping edit and translate a programming class to English. When talking about the Java library, the initial translator is using the term Java "made-up" classes. So for a list of available Java interfaces, the document says something along the lines of

*"Java comes with plenty made-up interfaces like List, Set and Collection."*

This is a document for novice programmers and I want to be precise. My instinct is to use "built-in", [as seen here](http://argouml-stats.tigris.org/documentation/manual-0.26/ch24s04.html).

I realize that this is not strictly a programming question. But I feel it is unlikely to be answered with precision by the English Language and Usage board. Whether to ask this sort of question of StackOverflow [was discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142723/questions-about-terminology-related-to-computer-programming)and I tend to agree with the comments under the accepted answer. I hope that doesn't offend anyone.

**Update**: I eventually used a  brief variety of phrases, inspired by the following passage in Joyce Farrel's *Java Programming* (6th Edition):

> Of particular value is the Java application programming interface,
>   more commonly referred to as the Java API. The Java API is also called
>   the Java class library; it contains information about how to use every
>   prewritten Java class, including lists of all the methods you can use
>   with the classes.

Thanks to the responders.

Comment: API is a word you might consider using. [See the javadoc root.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Comment: Sample sentences also include things like "Java API offers a large number of made-up classes". I get the sense that they are trying to distinguish one part of the API from another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wiki calls it a standard code library, so I would write:
"Java comes with a standard code library providing interfaces and classes like List, Set, Collection"
[Java Class Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Class_Library)

Comment: It isn't exactly what I went for but it is pretty close. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

"Java comes with a huge standard library providing interfaces and classes like List, Set, Collection."

Technically, there is no difference between user-defined classes and classes bundled with particular Java runtime.